# How to set message per second limit for users on ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd

I want to limit message per second for users, for example, each user can send 3 messages per second, but I couldn't find a configuration setting to do that.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Would limiting the number of bytes each user is allowed to send work for you as well?

Comment: @Dunedan no I want to limit message per second for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dunedan mentioned, there is **shaper** that measures traffic in bytes/second: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#shapers

And the oly other related option I can think is for MUC rooms: **min_message_interval** https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#mod-muc

Comment: Is this for per-user limitation

Comment: Yes, the Shaper is per client connection, and the second says: "min_message_interval: Number: This option defines the minimum interval between two messages send by an occupant in seconds. This option is global and valid for all rooms."